# Problem accessing Internet on Linux (kubuntu)

Tags: linux, internet, mac-address

I am new to Linux (in fact just installed it last night). I am setting up my internet. I made a switch from Windows 7 to Linux in order to learn it.

On Windows 7 I was accessing the internet by spoofing my mac address with the mac Address of guy who use to live in my room before. When I changed my mac address all the settings were automatically configured (IP address, subnet mask, default gateway). I tried the same approach with Linux today. I changed the mac address of my ethernet card, but unfortunately it isn't working for some reason. When I checked the settings I found that although my IP address as well as my subnet mask were configured automatically, the same as were on Windows, for some reason my default gateway was 130.83.219.127 (on Windows it used to be 130.83.219.126).

Now since I am not a network expert I don't exactly know what the hell this means. I wonder if maybe Linux users are assigned a different Gateway than Windows users? (I don't even know if this Statement makes sense since I don't have any idea of networks)

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you connecting wireless or a by cable?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87543/how-can-i-change-the-default-gateway

Comment: I am using cable...

Answer (score 2):

(If you previously use other method to change MAC address than this, restore them back to the default settings)

For Kubuntu, there's a "Network Manager" icon on the right side of the bottom bar(or panel, which a KDE icon is on the left).  Click on it, then click on the connection that is active you should find a way to edit the connection settings.  At last fill in the spoofed MAC address into the "Cloned MAC address" textbox of the "Wired" tab.

[image: Connection setting dialog]
**Note: The "Restrict to device" textbox should be remain blank if you don't know what it means.  If it's not blank, make it blank.**

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention which linux you're using I'll just assume you're using something with the ip utility(new debian or ubuntu or arch linux).
To change your default gateway type `ip route del default via 130.83.219.127` this deletes your current default gateway. Then add the new one: `ip route add default via 130.83.219.126`.

If you aren't 100% sure your MAC-Spoofing worked try `ip link show` there should be multiple lines, one starting with 1: lo and one starting with 2: eth0 or enp2s0 or something equal, this is your NIC. the link/ether field shows your mac-address if it isn't spoofed correctly first off shut down the NIC: `ip link set eth0 down` then sppof the mac `ip link set dev eth0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` and then set the interface back up `ip link set eth0 up`
Note: you might have to change eth0